# Powershell - Hashtable in Foreach statement

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to get an idea of how to go about this.

In a for each loop. Do you need to define the variables before using them in a hash table for `TITLE`,`DEPARTMENT`,`MANANGER`,`OFFICE`

Currently, this does not set anything for the users in the `foreach` statement.

```
Foreach ($userdata in $datafile) {
    $SetADUserdetails = @{
        Identity=$userdata.Adusername
        Title = $userdata.title
        Office=$userdata.office
        Department=$userdata.department
        Manager=$userdata.manager
    }
    Set-ADUser @SetADUserdetails  # Need to add Domain Controller Parameter
}
```

This is how the datafile looks like.
GivenName,Surname,Office,Title,Path,Manager,Department,Adusername

I'm sure if I set the variable first and then match the variable to hash table keys, it going to work.

Please let me know your thought. I'm fair new to PowerShell. I tried searching the internet for the correct method. No luck. just want to double-check before I define variables.

Comment: It's not clear what `$datafile` is, in addition `$ADusername` is not defined in the code you're showing us, `Identity=$ADusername` should be `Identity=$userdata` most likely. There is not enough information in your question to help you further.

Comment: Hi I have provided the header for datafile.

Comment: How are you importing the file? Does `Set-ADUser` give you any error?

Comment: You don't need to define e.g. `$userdata.office` before using it. If a property does not exist in an object, PowerShell will simply give you `$null` as the value.

Comment: According to MS document you may have to both Identity and Replace for setting up those properties. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: Please edit the question to show where you get `$datafile` from. In its current state we can only do guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, variables are rendered at runtime. When you define the hashtable the key will have the variable assigned at the time the hashtable was defined, or the last value that was set for that key with `=`.

In your code example, the keys of `$SetADUserdetails` have no value because the `$userdata` Properties have no value. Make sure that `$datafile` has the correct entries you are expecting and confirm each iteration of `$userdata` has *some* value. Either `$datafile` is incorrect or you are referencing each column by the wrong column name.